# 3 foreign key to 1 table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table for users that kept user's info and a table for user's vacation .in my project everyone who wants goes vacation tells a person and that person creates a request, another person must confirm that request. in user's vacation, I have  3 columns. one for a person who wants to go on vacation called `userId` and one who created a request called `creatorUserId`, and another for confirming called `acceptorId`  .the problem is when I want to show the acceptor name I got null references error.
here are my relations.

```
    public class User
{
    public User()
    {

    }

    
    [Key] public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "نام کاربری")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد نمایید")]
    [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "{0} نمیتواند بیشتر از {1} کاراکتر باشد")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "نام ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد نمایید")]
    [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "{0} نمیتواند بیشتر از {1} کاراکتر باشد")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "نام خانوادگی")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد نمایید")]
    [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "{0} نمیتواند بیشتر از {1} کاراکتر باشد")]
    public string LastName  { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "کد ملی")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد نمایید")]
    
    [Range(0, 9999999999, ErrorMessage = "{0} نمیتواند بیشتر از {1} عدد باشد")]
    public string SocialNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "ایمیل")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد نمایید")]
    [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "{0} نمیتواند بیشتر از {1} کاراکتر باشد")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "ایمیل وارد شده معتبر نمی باشد.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "کد فعال سازی ایمیل")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "{0} نمیتواند بیشتر از {1} کاراکتر باشد")]
    public string ActiveCodeEmail { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "کلمه عبور")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد نمایید")]
    [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "{0} نمیتواند بیشتر از {1} کاراکتر باشد")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "وضعیت")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "آواتار")]
    [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "{0} نمیتواند بیشتر از {1} کاراکتر باشد")]
    public string UserAvatar { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "تاریخ ثبت نام")]
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsDelete { get; set; }

    #region Relations

    public  Collection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

  public Collection<UserVacation> UserVacations { get; set; }


    [InverseProperty("AcceptorUserId")]
    public Collection<UserVacation> aceeptorUserVacation { get; set; }


    [InverseProperty("CreatorId")]
    public Collection<UserVacation> CreatorIdUserVacation { get; set; }


    #endregion
```

user vacation

```
    public class UserVacation
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "آیدی کاربر")]

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "نوع مرخصی")]
    public int VacationType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "مدت زمان")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد نمایید")]
    public int Duration { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "کاربر ایجاد کننده")]
    public int CreatorUserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "زمان ایجاد درخواست")]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "کاربر قبول کننده")]
    public int? AcceptorId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "زمان خروج")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? ExitTime { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "زمان ورود ")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? EnterTime { get; set; }

    public VacationStatus Status { get; set; }




    #region Relations


    public virtual User.User User { get; set; }

    
    [ForeignKey("AcceptorId")]
    public User.User AcceptorUserId { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("CreatorUserId")]
    public User.User CreatorId { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("VacationType")]
    public vacationType Type { get; set; }



    #endregion



}

public enum VacationStatus
{
    Pending,
    Accepted,
    Rejected,
}
```

my method for getting information

```
        public async Task<showVacationForReport> GetVacationByUserId(int id, int pageId = 1, int filter = 0, string fromDate = "", string toDate = "")
    {
        IQueryable<UserVacation> vacations = _context.UserVacations.Where(v => v.UserId == id);
        
        if (filter != 0)
        {
            switch (filter)
            {
                case 1:
                    vacations = vacations.Where(v => v.VacationType == 1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    vacations = vacations.Where(v => v.VacationType == 2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    vacations = vacations.Where(v => v.VacationType == 3);
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromDate))
        {
            DateTime FromDate = fromDate.ToMiladi();
            vacations = vacations.Where(v => v.ExitTime >= FromDate);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(toDate))
        {
            DateTime ToDate = toDate.ToMiladi();
           vacations = vacations.Where(v => v.EnterTime <= ToDate);
        }
        //show item in page
        int take = 20;
        int skip = (pageId - 1) * take;

        showVacationForReport ShowReport = new showVacationForReport()
        {
            CurrentPage = pageId,
            PageCount = vacations.Count()/take,
            UserVacations = await vacations.Include(u=>u.User).Include(v=>v.Type).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToListAsync(),
        };
        return ShowReport;
    }
```

Comment: *"the problem is when I want to show the acceptor name I got null references error"* Show the code which retrieves the `UserVacation` (I guess ?)  object(s) from database. Most likely you forgot to call `Include` (see [Load Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/))

Comment: thanks for the reply. I post my method. I include user's table and just can get the users who want to go on vacation.

Comment: Alright, I see you have `Include` for `User`, `Type`, but not `AcceptorUserId`  (non intuitive name btw, why not just `Acceptor`, this `Id` at the end really sounds like FK identifier, while this is navigation property) which is causing you null reference exception.

Comment: yes, that's right. I dint include AcceptorUserId .thank you very much.